# Display VBS variable in command prompt

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, command-prompt

I would like to know how to display variable values in command prompt. 
Following is the `vbs` code:

```
 For i=0 To 10
 // I should display this variable value in command prompt
 Next
```

If I write `Shell.run`(`a.bat`) inside loop, this will open command prompt 10 times.
But i want all 10 values to be displayed in single command prompt.

Comment: How do you (want to) start your script? What is the purpose/content of a.bat? Have you considered using WScript.Echo? (BTW: Your loop loops 11 times, comments are marked with ' (not //) in VBScript, the parameter to .Run needs to be quoted, and you must not use param list () in a Sub call)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `WScript.Echo`:

```
For i = 0 To 10
  WScript.Echo i
Next
```

You'll want to use CSCRIPT, either explicitly:

```
cscript vecho.vbs
```

Or make CSCRIPT the default:

```
cscript //H:CScript
```

Comment: Nothing. I just converted host from wscript to cscript and used WScript.Echo command. I called VBS file from Bat file so that everything got displayed in Command prompt :)  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Yes, if run the .vbs script via CSCRIPT then *WScript.Echo* will print to the prompt window, else will popup a message box. Then work with CSCRIPT you can use as well *WScript.StdOut.Write* and *WScript.StdOut.WriteLine*

```
For i = 0 To 10
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine i
Next
```

Also with *Shell.Run* you can get only the exit code, and to redirect the output from your .bat file, you'll need *Shell.Exec* method. There is a nice example on how to use *Exec* into [Windows Script 5.6 Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2764). It's a must have doc file anyway.